# Search string in a txt file with Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to locate the beginning of a string in a txt file using a Java program which I will then have to delete from the txt file. The problem is that it doesn't recognize the string I want to search and delete.

This is the example of the txt file:

[image]

I want to locate the string `"(GmmiVariables)"` and subsequently delete it from the file. I wrote this code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader b = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("QD48.txt"));
     String s="";

     while((s=b.readLine()) != null) {
     if(s.contains("(GmmiVariables)"))
        System.out.println(s);
        s=b.readLine();
   }
 }
```

It doesn't print anything to me even if the string is present in the file and I can't understand why. Will it be due to the fact that txt files have spaces between each string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you reading the line twice?

```
while((s=b.readLine())/* read first time */ != null) {
    if(s.contains("(GmmiVariables)"))
       System.out.println(s);
       s=b.readLine();/* read second time */
}
```

remove the second `b.readLine()`, you miss *alternate lines* in your text file. `GmmiVariables` is on the **10th line**. Change your while loop to look something like this and check if that works->

```
while((s=b.readLine()) != null) {
    if(s.contains("(GmmiVariables)"))
       System.out.println(s);
}
```